# import error: no module named spectral

Tags: python, spectral-python

I have already installed all the SPy dependencies and trying to import the spectral module in ipython version3.0 and getting this error : no module named spectral. what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: What statement are you using to import this module?

Comment: from spectral import *

Comment: @RachJain it's not great practice to import modules using `*`, for readability purposes!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Spectral for Python 3 is:

1. Go to the installation page http://www.spectralpython.net/installation.html
2. Click on the link "Python Package Index (PyPI)". It will lead you to the download page: https://pypi.org/project/spectral/.
3. Click on Download files, save the "spectral.tar.gz" into your computer.
4. Extract the files (right click -> Extract here).
5. On terminal type "cd /home/user/Downloads/spectral-0.19" (or use the path to the folder you just unconpressed).
6. On terminal type "sudo python3 setup.py install"

Obs: if you use "sudo python setup.py install", as shown at installation page, it will install Spectral for Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "pip install spectral"on terminal to install the spectral package.
you can refer to "https://pypi.org/project/spectral/".